# Why does the bootstrap .row class have a default margin-left of -30px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I do boostrap I have to use the class "row" ...

When you look at my test design:

[image]

Why I am forced with a margin-left of -30px?

With this html I would expect 3 rows sharing each column 33% of the whole available width:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="background-color: pink;" class="span4">
            This is a label
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: violet;" class="span4">
            This is a textbox
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: slateblue;" class="span4">
            This is a button
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div style="background-color: orange;" class="span4">
            This is a label
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: orangered;" class="span4">
            This is a textbox
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: yellow;" class="span4">
            This is a button
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div style="background-color: seagreen;" class="span4">
            This is a label
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: green;" class="span4">
            This is a textbox
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: lightgreen;" class="span4">
            This is a button
        </div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

The gray area with the buttons is from this code:

```
<div style="background-color: gray;">
    <div class="pager">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind="css: { disabled: !hasPrevious() }, click: previous">previous</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind="css: { disabled: !hasNext() },     click: next">next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <span data-bind="text: stepNumber()" />
            <span>/</span>
            <span data-bind="text: stepsLength" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <!-- ko compose: { model: activeStep,
        transition: 'entrance' } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

1. Why does the whole 3-column design fall together when I remove the -30px margin-left?
2. How should I change my code to really get a 3 column layout each column having the same width. This is what span4 should do.

Comment: that is the gutter. you can change that in the less source files but you'll need to rebuild after you change it. There are different gutters based on various media queries.

Comment: @origin1tech so it seems you are not a friend of bootstrap?

Comment: I like bootstrap and use it all the time. There are certain concessions I find using it. In fact rather than chop up the source (the less itself) I tend to override or just concede to use as intended. The web is moving toward continuity over granular control. Users care less about elaborate layouts and more about speed and functionality. Say as you will but bootstrap aids greatly in that continuity.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**question 1**:

the `span`s all have a `margin-left` of `30px` to create some space between the single blocks. this space should only appear **between** the single `span`s and **not at the beginning** (or end) of the `row`. to accomplish this, there are several possibilitys - for example:

- create a negative `margin` with the space-with on the row (this is what bootstrap does)
- use the `:first-child` selector to remove margin-left on the first `span` in a row
- *[to be continued]*

i can only assume the bootstrap uses the first option because it's more compatible with older browsers (most likely IE 7 and below).

a little example: lets say your `span`s have a width of 100, a space of 10 and there are 3 in a row.

- your total row-width in this case should be 320 (100 + 10 + 100 + 10 + 100 = 320)
- a single span has a width of 110 (100 width + 10 magin-left)

  - simply adding those up would give you a width of 330 and an ugly space of 10 at the beginning (**10 +** 100 + 10 + 100 + 10 + 100 = 330)
  - "subtract" 10 with one of the listed methods (**-10** + 10 + 100 + 10 + 100 + 10 + 100 = 320)

    - *hooray, we've created great things with the power of math*

**question 2**
if you use `span4`s, you already have 3 columns of the same width. you don't need to change anything.

Comment: **+42** for _"hooray, we've created great things with the power of math"_

Comment: What is the reason of having some 30px space preformatted? I do not want that I have to use a library and then have to override the default settings because they seem pointless or destroy my layout. I guess I understood your mathematical sample but what should that show me? that an ugly space of 10 at the beginning is stupid? yes that it is indeed, but what more?

Comment: nothing more - thats just how bootsrap works. if you don't like this behaviour, just use another css-framework supporting grid-based layouts...

Answer (score 30):

Class `row` adds a

1. `clearfix`
2. negative `margin-left`
3. negative `margin-right`

**Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/120858

**With** negative margin at the beginning:

```
<div class="row">            
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

**Without** negative margin at the beginning:

```
<div>     
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's only the case because .container or .container-fluid has +15px padding. http://www.bootply.com/4dZkBaUKh3  As Kyle pointed out, just use columns without the container/row div wrappers and just add a clearfix if needed if you don't want to have any padding/margin.

Answer (score 7):

Because you don't need to use row-fluid anymore. All row does is perform the cleafix and apply the negative margin. This is typically correct for an accurate grid system. You can use containers or instead of using "row" you just use "clearfix" and you'll have the exact same behavior as before with no margin.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this issue is to use 
`class="container row"` instead of `class="row"` , this solution will make the row fit inside the container without horizontal overflow.

Comment: this does indeed work, but seems to be improper bootstrap, using mx-auto (class="row mx-auto) on the outermost row does the job in a more standard way

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Fluid mode and using less, a mixin is very usefull: **.offsetFirstChild (@columns)**

(see mixin.less of Bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$('<div>Test</div>').addClass('row').css("margin-left", 0).css("margin-right", 0).appendTo('.content');
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how is solves the problem?

Comment: It also fails to answer the question, instead it just adjust the margin.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid to use "container" on a separate "div", why don't define a specific class on a custom CSS?
I use:

```
.nomargin {margin: 0;}
```

and on HTML:

```
<div class="row nomargin">
 …
 </div>
```

Same result but more readable.

Comment: why the downvote? He don't want margins on a row? It's a simple solution as "m-0" but without "!important"...