# BootStrap Row not aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5 and I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="home-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-items-xs-middle">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h1 class="site-title text-xs-center text-md-left">
                    <span class="name">I'm Shivam Paw</span>
                    <span class="title">I create beautiful and bespoke websites to fit your needs</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="https://www.shivampaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/shivampaw.png" class="float-md-right img-fluid logo-me mx-auto" alt="Shivam Paw">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if you see the image below then you will see that the content is misaligned to the left. I saw a post on this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153497/bootstrap-row-class-contains-margin-left-and-margin-right-which-creates-problems) but it said you have to put the row class in a container which I have already done.

You can see the site live at https://www.shivampaw.com

[image: Misaligned Row]

I looked at the .row CSS which has margin for left and right of -15px. Removing those margins fixed it but I don't think that's how it should be?

Comment: are you asking about the Marging in the row class? Yes, bootstrap added it. and depent too of container-fluid and container. . . learn to use the container class.

Comment: @ccdiego5 did you read my question?...

Comment: very strange behavior. It looks like `margin-right: -15px;` has no effect on your row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some offending CSS in my style.css:

```
*, img.full-size{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Changing it to:

```
img.full-size{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image] If this is what you expect then look at your CSS. This is the line centering your content

```css
.text-xs-center {
    text-align: center!important;
}
```

This  should fix it though

```css
.site-title {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I want the text centered. Look at the position carefully, it isn't centered properly.